# glReadPixels and save to image

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I have app, where user drags and drops image, and it is being redrawn with `OpenGL` for some aviable processing. Everything works. And when user wants to save his image it works like that:

```
glReadPixels -> NSBitmapImageRep -> NSData -> Write to file
```

This works too. Almost. With some images it is not working as it should work.

For example:

***.png***

when I open and save this image:
[image]

I get:
[image]

And if I open and save this image:
[image]

I get:
[image]

***.jpg***

If I open and save:
[image]

I get:
[image]

And when I open and save:
[image]

I get:
[image]

So sometimes images saves badly. Why is it happening?

---

This is how my `NSBitmapImageRep` is allocated:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL pixelsWide:_image_width pixelsHigh:_image_height bitsPerSample:8 samplesPerPixel:3 hasAlpha:NO isPlanar:NO colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace bytesPerRow:3 * _image_width bitsPerPixel:0];
```

And `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is not edited.

Comment: Are you using the default `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` of 4 (bytes) and trying to grab RGB (3 byte) images?

Comment: I haven't edited GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT and I'm grabbing RGB image

Comment: I added `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 3);` before glReadPixels and it haven't affected anything

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: Valid values for pack alignment are 1, 2, 4 and 8. Pack alignment is not the size of a single pixel, but the address alignment for row starts. I'm quite sure you want to set GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before feting the pixel data you must tell OpenGL how to "format" it. This means setting all the GL_PACK_ parameters of [→glPixelStore](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml). Most important for you is the alignment parameter. Also keep in mind to write the files with the right number of components per pixels, and also read the right components from OpenGL.

Comment: And where `glPixelStore` parameter should be set? Before setting NSBitmapImageRep? Or after setting OpenGL context? Or where?

Comment: OpenGL is a state machine. You set state right before it matters. In your case right before calling glReadPixels.

Comment: I added `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 3);` before glReadPixels and it haven't affected anything

Answer (score 0):

I had the same

You need just setup correct bytesPerRow

```
bytesPerRow:(width*3+3)&~3
```